# calculation string of list without comma into new list in python

Tags: python, string, list

I would like to convert the following list and multiply 0.2 to get new list.

Here is the input: without comma in the list

```
x =['10' '20' '30']
```

The ideal output is:

```
output =[2,4,6]
```

I used the the code `",".join(str(i) for i in x)`. It is not working.

Comment: "The output is:" - is this what you *want* to get, or what you *actually* get?

Comment: `str.join` gives you a string. If you want a list, this method won't help you. Do you know how to turn a string into an int? Do you know how to multiply numbers? If yes, where's the problem?

Comment: Try `[int(round(.2 * int(i))) for i in x]` (and you need commas in the definition of `x` or you will just concatenate the strings).

Comment: @timgeb my issue is x = ['10' '20' '30'] without comma,I am not sure how to convert it into ['10','20','30']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
x =['10' ,'20' ,'30']
a=[]
for i in x:
    a.append(int(int(i)*0.2))
print(a)
```

output:

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

if your list contains two digit numbers only then you can do something like this,

```
x =['10' '20' '30']
i=x[0]
for j in range(0,len(i),2):
    print(int(int(i[j:j+2])*0.2))
```

output-

```
2
4
6
```

Comment: my issue is x = ['10' '20' '30'] without comma,I am not sure how to convert it into ['10','20','30']

Comment: @Rya but without the comma list would be `['102030']` and you can't split this list,because you don't know which is the number either `102` or `10`.

Comment: @Rya are you taking the x =['10' '20' '30'] from user as input if not how you are getting that `x`

Comment: yes. I am taking  x =['10' '20' '30'] from user as input.

Comment: @Rya can you provide the code which takes input, so i can help you

Comment: the code to get x =['10' '20' '30'] cannot be changed,so what I am thinking is how to change x =['10' '20' '30'] into ['10', '20', '30']